# Null pointer exception while trying to use DriverPropertyInfo[]

Tags: jdbc, null

Code:

```
DriverPropertyInfo[] Information = new DriverPropertyInfo[1];
String[] Names_Arr = new String[n.size()];
Names_Arr = n.toArray(Names_Arr);
Information[0].choices = Names_Arr;
```

I get a "Null pointer exception" in the last line. Why?

Note: n is an `ArrayList` of strings.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're actually trying to accomplish, but here is a very simple example of how to use the `getPropertyInfo` method of the JDBC `Driver` object:

```java
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:memdb";
Properties p = new Properties();
Driver d = DriverManager.getDriver(connectionUrl);
DriverPropertyInfo[] dpi = d.getPropertyInfo(connectionUrl, p);
for (int i = 0; i < dpi.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(dpi[i].name);
}
```

The console output displays the `name` of each property in the array of `DriverPropertyInfo` objects that `getPropertyInfo` returned:

```
user
password
get_column_name
ifexists
default_schema
shutdown
```

More information on the attributes returned can be found at

[Class DriverPropertyInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverPropertyInfo.html)

Comment: I am making like a simulation to the JDBC but for an Offline database existed in directory in my computer.
so the interfaces are not implemented and my task to implement them .
so i am trying here to get a list of database names and put them in choices of driverpropertyinfo to use them later.
that's all.